# Azure Functions for Node Shutdown Hook?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Is there a shutdown hook for JS Azure Functions?  The C# library supports a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens) which allows the user to supply a shutdown hook, but I can't find any doc on the equivalent for the v2 Node Functions runtime.

My use case is shutting down a DB connection pool gracefully.  Right now, there is a deadlock bug (I don't have a link yet - I'm waiting on MS support to send me a link to the "known-issue" that they cited in email), and the MS team applied a work-around in the runtime that throws an exception on timeout to restart the runtime:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostExceptionHandler[0]
An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
System.TimeoutException: The operation 'ScanLogs' with id '***' did not complete in '00:02:00'.
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.TimeoutHandler.ExecuteWithTimeout[T](String operationName, String clientRequestId, IWebJobsExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Func`1 operation) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\TimeoutHandler.cs:line 30
```

When this happens, the functions process exits immediately and every connection in our pool times out on the server side, which registers as a "Failed Connection" in our DB metrics.

I'm going to start experimenting with the standard `process.on()` hooks.  Maybe `process.on('beforeExit')` will work, but since it is obviously catching the uncaughtException, I think it may then call process.exit() directly, which will bypass that, so I was wondering if anyone else had done this.  I looked a little at the [async-exit-hook package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-exit-hook) but I am afraid to install anything that could interfere with the parent exception handlers that come with the SDK and whatever cleanup that it is already doing.